# Set Theory problem with unique numbers

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Let $A_0$ be the set {$1, 2, 3, 4$}. Let $A_{i+1}$ be the set of all possible sums which
can be obtained by adding two numbers in $A_i$ , where the two numbers do
not have to be different. How many unique numbers does $A_8$ contain?

Obviously, this seems very difficult to begin with. Without trial-and-error what can you do?

Comment: My hint would have been to calculate $A_2$ by hand.  Then you might have noticed for yourself what paw88789 pointed out.

Comment: @MJD, Wont it be natural to calculate $A_1$ first?

Comment: Yes, $A_1$, then $A_2$.

Comment: @MJD, will you assist me? $A_0$ = {1, 2, 3, 4} so $A_1 = ${2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 7, 4, 5, 7, 5, 6, 7, 8}

There is repitition? So how should I order this set $A_1$?

Comment: Sets never have repetition.  An element is either in a set, or it isn't.  The set $\{2,2,3\}$ is the same set as $\{2,3\}$, because each one contains 2, 3, and nothing else.

Comment: @MJD, Ah - so: $A_1$ = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8} Then what is the next step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

It isn't too hard to show that if you form sums of two elements from a set of positive integers of the form $\{a, a+1, a+2,\dots, b\}$, your possible sums (allowing repetition) are $\{2a, 2a+1, 2a+2,\dots, 2b\}$.

Comment: From {$a, a+1, a+1, ... b$} how do you get to: {$2a, 2a  + 1....$} ?? (+1), good answer.